# passing date variable to macro for sysfunc processing

Tags: sas, sas-macro

below is my little problem to create a macro and passing in a date variable. Without using the date variable, it works with results as below.

```
%macro x();
%let i=-1;
%let dts = %sysfunc(today());
%put &dts; /*ok*/
%let yymm1 = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i));
%put &yymm1; /*ok*/

%let mth_beg = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i,B),date9.);
%let mth_end = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i,E),date9.);
%put &mth_beg &mth_end; /*01JAN2018 31JAN2018*/
/*** proc sql code below ** */
%mend;
%x();
```

log:
21231
21185
01JAN2018 
31JAN2018

Now I create a macro around it and got the following error:

```
%macro x(dts1);

%let i=-1;
/*%let dts = %sysfunc(today());*/
%let dts = %sysfunc(&dts1);
%put &dts; /*ok*/
%let yymm1 = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i));
%put &yymm1; /*ok*/

%let mth_beg = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i,B),date9.);
%let mth_end = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i,E),date9.);
%put &mth_beg &mth_end; /*01JAN2018 31JAN2018*/
/*** proc sql code below ** */
%mend;
%x(16JAN2018);
```

ERROR: Function name missing in %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function reference.
JAN2018)
ERROR: Expected close parenthesis after macro function invocation not found.
))
ERROR: Expected close parenthesis after macro function invocation not found.
ERROR: Expected close parenthesis after macro function invocation not found.
,B),date9.) ,E),date9.)

I am not sure how to let SAS treat the date passed in as a recognized date. I know i probably used the sysfunc(&dts) wrongly or the date passed in need to adhere to certain format. i just want the date to replace today(). Can you help? I am a SAS newbie.

thanks

Comment: What values do you want to pass into your macro when you call it?  Do you want to pass in character strings that look to you like a date `16FEB2018`? Or do you want to pass in a valid SAS date, such as a date literal `"16FEB2018"d`, or a simple number of days since 01JAN1960?

Comment: I am flexible cos I am the one who decide the passing. Cos I will be doing this e.g. %x(16Feb2018); %x(16Jan2018);..Etc basically I am passing in monthly data points to run monthly reports. So as long sas accept my values.

Comment: So if you pass in values like `16FEB2018` and you want to use it as an actual date you will need to convert it to a date literal in the body of the macro.  `"&mvar"d`

Comment: Thanks it works. But I would like to know the difference btw
%let dts = %sysfunc(today()); and 
%let dts = &quot;%dts1&quot;d (i.e . &quot;16jan2018&quot;d. Both  steps point to below step. 
%let yymm1 = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&amp;dts,&amp;i));

Assuming today is  16jan2018, I know %let dts = %sysfunc(today()); resolves to SAS integer value. But  &quot;16jan2018&quot;D is not the SAS integer right? I just am not sure why the difference in treatment.

Comment: See answer below. You can represent the same date as either an integer or a date literal.  Just make sure you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the date in `"` and end with a `d`.  That will tell SAS to convert the string to a date:

```
%macro x(dts1);

%let i=-1;
/*%let dts = %sysfunc(today());*/
%let dts = "&dts1"d; /*Change here!*/
%put &dts; /*ok*/
%let yymm1 = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i));
%put &yymm1; /*ok*/

%let mth_beg = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i,B),date9.);
%let mth_end = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&dts,&i,E),date9.);
%put &mth_beg &mth_end; /*01JAN2018 31JAN2018*/
/*** proc sql code below ** */
%mend;
%x(16JAN2018);
```

Comment: It works . May I know if %sysfunc(today()) and "18jan2018"d are the same? I tot the former is an sas integer (number of days since 1960) , is the latter also the same ?

Comment: Correct, assuming today() is the 18th of Jan, 2018. ;-)  All dates in SAS are integers as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

change    %let dts = %sysfunc(&dts1); to

```
%let dts = %sysfunc(inputn(&dts1,date9. ));
```

Comment: Or even `anydtdte.` for maximum compatibility!

Comment: For %sysfunc(inputn(&dts1,date9.

Does it matter what format I set to , I.e. other format instead of data9.?

Comment: yes, you need to use format accordingly as your macro variable . please use %let dts = %sysfunc(inputn(&dts1,anydtdte. )); for almost any date as suggested by user667849

Answer (score 0):

SAS stores dates as the number of days since 01JAN1960. So if you do not attach a date format to the date value it will just look like an integer.

```
%let today=%sysfunc(today());
```

You can then use that integer anywhere you would use a date value.

```
%let next_month=%sysfunc(intnx(month,&today,1,b));
```

You can also represent dates by using a date literal. To make a date literal you represent the date value using something the DATE informat can read (like 16FEB2018, 16feb18, 16-FEB-2018, etc.) enclosed in quotes with the letter `d` appended.

```
%let today="%sysfunc(today(),date9)"d ;
%let date_string=13FEB2018;
%let date_value="&date_string"d ;
```

So date literals will work in SAS code and when you use the `%sysfunc()` macro function to call a SAS function (like INTNX) and they will work in the `%sysevalf()` macro function.  But the `%eval()` macro function will not recognize date literals.  So you will need to use `%sysevalf()` if you want use arithmetic or comparisons of date literals in macro logic.

```
%if %sysevalf(&today > '01JAN2018'd) %then ....
%let tomorrow=%sysevalf(&today +1);
```